# Error installing python3.7 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.7

I'm trying to install Python3.7 on ubuntu 16.04. I tried the installation steps on the internet, but I got an error code.

My installation steps:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.7
```

And my error:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3.7
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.7'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.7
```

I tried this method:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa   
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt install python3.7
```

But I still got the same error:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install python3.7  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.7
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.7'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.7'
```

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 1):

See ["supported Ubuntu and Python versions" here](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). It seems Ubuntu 16.04 is not supported by `deadsnakes` anymore, probably because [it too is end-of-life](https://endoflife.date/ubuntu).

I would suggest

- upgrading to a supported version of Ubuntu,
- or if that's not an option, you may be able to install the desired version of Python with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).